# Fancybox 2.0 left/right buttons to the title

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi there is a way to add left/right buttons to the title [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ANLxC/3/). I would have prev button — title from html title tag — next button on title inside (not interesting to image 1 of..)

I try this:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect: 'none',
  closeEffect: 'none',
  helpers: {
    title: {
      type : 'inside'
    }
  },
  afterLoad: function() {
    if(this.index > 0) {
      this.title += '<a href="#" onclick="$.fancybox.prev();return false;" ' +
                    'id="fancybox-prev"></a>';
    }
    if(this.index < this.group.length - 1) {
      this.title += '<a href="#" onclick="$.fancybox.next();return false;" ' +
                    'id="fancybox-next"></a>';
    }
  }
});
```

but display only title from HTML tag title and not next-prev button.

**EDIT**

I solved it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    helpers: {
      title: {
        type: 'inside'
      }
    },
    afterLoad : function() {
      var title = this.title;
      this.title = '';
      if(this.index > 0) {
        this.title += '&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="$.fancybox.prev(); ' +
                      'return false;" title="previous">' +
                      '<img src="prev.gif" border ="0" alt="prev" /></a>';
      }
      this.title += ' ' + title + ' ';
      if(this.index < this.group.length - 1) {
        this.title += '&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="$.fancybox.next(); ' +
                      'return false;" title="next">' +
                      '<img src="next.gif" border ="0" alt="next" /></a>';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

prev.gif and next.gif are two image that I have created.

Comment: Please turn your answer into a real answer below. You can mark it as accepted after two days. That will make the question go away from the Unanswered Questions tab.